# Standard RAM spacing on a branded motherboard?

Tags: memory

I was wondering if there was a standard spacing between DIMM slots on branded motherboards or if they're all different. I want to get [G.SKILL Ripjaws](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231486&ignorebbr=1) RAM.

But I have RAM spacing like this:

[image: pic]

Am I able to fit it without problem?

Comment: The spacing on the motherboard will be the same.  The size of memory will depend on several factors.  Check the specifications of the memory, some come with heatsinks, which increase their size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that photo (and getting the RAM spec from google) and the comparing to your newegg link - there shouldn't be any problem fitting that into your PC.

Width-wise, although there isnt an exact industry standard spacing, you will find there is almost always plenty of space and this is certainly the case for you from what I can see.